# Convert part of c-style string to int

Tags: c

I have an array `input` which may contain a number. I know where in the array it will appear (if it does appear): after the `:`. (Future inputs may include multiple numbers, each after some text and a `:`).

I'm able to create a new array, then copy from `input` to the new array starting at my token, continuing while I read characters `0-9`. I then call `atoi` on the new array.

It would be somewhat simpler if I were able to say `atoi(array, start, end)`, converting only the portion of the array that contains my number and eliminating the need for a copy-to-new-array loop.

I can't see any such overloading of the [`atoi` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/).

Is there an easy way to convert only a portion of a c-style string into a number that doesn't involve me writing my own `atoi(const char * str, int start, int end)`?

Comment: There is no `overloading` in C...

Comment: You can use `strtol`: it returns pointer to first non-numeric char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [strtoul](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/) as suggested by D.Shawley, you could do the following:

**Code**

```
char* str = ":12 sdfsdf :45:18";
char* p = str;
while (*p)
{
    if (*p++ == ':')
        printf("%d\n", strtoul(p, &p, 10));
}
```

**Output**

```
12
45
18
```

[See the codepad](http://codepad.org/s9Hs5xlo)

**atoi version**

It's also possible using atoi ([codepad](http://codepad.org/nmZN2FxT)):

```
char* str = ":12 sdfsdf :45:18";
char* p = str;
while (*p)
{
    if (*p++ == ':')
        printf("%d\n", atoi(p));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`strtoul`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/) instead.  Just adjust or offset the starting address with an index.  The output pointer will let you know where the parsing ended.

Answer (score 0):

No, I do not know such function.

There is also no overloading in C.

However, writing your own atoi is not that difficult.

```
int atoi_se(const char * str, int start, int end) {
  char* startPtr = str+start;
  char* endPtr = str+end;
  char savedChr = *endPtr;
  *endPtr = '\0';
  int retVal = strtol(startPtr, NULL, 10);
  *endPtr = savedChr;
  return retVal;
}
```

Note: I skipped the defensive coding required for such a function.

Answer (score 0):

`atoi` should work fine. Just pass it your start position (rather than your entire `input` array), and it will read as many digits as it can. Other characters after the numeric digits will be ignored.